# Is the “Is it that <fact>?” construct valid English?

Tags: questions, tag-questions

As an alternative to saying “<fact>, right?”, [@Bob-the-zealot suggests](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/30433/1347) “Is it that <fact>?” (the example given was “Is it that you are going tomorrow on the 11:30 flight?”). I'm aware of constructs like “How is it that <fact>?” and “Is it true that <fact>?”, but **is “Is it that <fact>?” valid English**? And if so, is it restricted to a region, historical period or otherwise?

Comment: It's grammatical, but we can't tell this without clicking your link.  `[fact]` doesn't give us enough information.  Could you please edit your question to include at least a complete sentence as an example?

Comment: I tried to think of whether this was valid, "Is it that the sky is blue", "is the sky blue", however, no; this does not sound correct to me. I don't know of any time I would say "that" to define a fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A native English speaker would not say "Is it that [fact]?" in such a context, but instead "Is it true that [fact]?"

"Is it that [fact]?" may appear in other contexts, with *it* standing in for something like *the problem*:

> People grimace when I sing. Is it that I am a bad singer?